# The iTunes Connect review process for submitted apps is not simple and linear

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-store

I have two apps in queue for review by Apple.

I had uploaded two app recently.

```
App 1 >> New App uploaded on 5-Jun-14

App 2 >> Update for app uploaded on 4-Jun-14 (one day before of App 1)
```

Status I see is

```
App 1 >> In review

App 2 >> Waiting for review
```

I just don't understand, how can the app that I uploaded later is in review first? I've asked twice for expedited reviews and they were denied. This is something **frustrating me**.

Does any one know how app approval process goes?

I wanted the update to get approved asap.

Comment: They might have different categories. Is one an update? or are both new?

Comment: @Rob : App 2 is update (Category Health and Fitness), App 1 is new app (Category Business) ...

Comment: @user3728970 The differencei in category can cause this as they're being reviewed by different teams.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe apple prioritises new apps over updates.

If your update contains major bug fixes you can request to get it expedited.

You can checkout recent review times here: http://appreviewtimes.com

Comment: I asked for Expedited review, but they rejected two times...

Answer (score 2):

The web site [AppReviewTimes](http://appreviewtimes.com/) collates information about recent app review times. Reviews are currently taking about one week.

Long waits for reviews are not uncommon. Multi-week waits are not unusual; unwelcome but not uncommon.

If you need a swift review, [contact Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/) and ask for an **Expedited App Review**.

> **Expedited App Review**
>
> If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of
>   your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a
>   critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to
>   coincide with an event you are directly associated with.

Comment: I asked for Expedited review, but they rejected two times...

Comment: Then you have no choice but to wait. If you are developing Mac applications, consider selling through additional non-Apple reliant channels.

Comment: its an iOS app...